# find how many times and which columns a string is repeated

Tags: r, string, data.table, matching

My data consists of 6 strings per each element. It has string with 6 characters. The data has white space too.
I want to know how many times each string is repeated in all columns

for example P67809 is repeated 2 times in column a and column d
so the output should look likes

```
string   No     columns 
P67809   2       a,b
```

Based on this function I can assign a row number to each string

```
normalize <- function(x, delim) {
    x <- gsub(")", "", x, fixed=TRUE)
    x <- gsub("(", "", x, fixed=TRUE)
    idx <- rep(seq_len(length(x)), times=nchar(gsub(sprintf("[^%s]",delim), "", as.character(x)))+1)
    names <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), delim))
    return(setNames(idx, names))
}
```

Then I apply the function on all and each columns string like

```
myS <- lapply(mydata, normalize,";")
```

but I don't know how to then search and get the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `melt` the data from 'wide' to 'long' format.  Split the 'value' column with `;` to get a `list` output.  We set the names of the `list` as the 'variable' column of 'dM'.  Then `stack` the `list` to a two column output, and get the frequency count with 'tbl'.  It may be easier to understand the result from the 'tbl' output.

```
library(reshape2)
dM <- melt(mydata, id.var=NULL) 
lst1 <- setNames(strsplit(dM$value, ";"), dM$variable)
tbl <- table(stack(lst1)[2:1])
tbl
values
#ind   A4QPH2 O60814 P0CG47 P0CG48 P14923 P15924 P19338 P35908 P42356 P57053 P58876 P62750 P62807 P62851 P62979 P63241 P67809 Q02413 Q06830 Q07955 Q16658 Q5QNW6 Q6IS14 Q8N8J0 Q93079 Q969S3
#  a 0      1      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0
#  b 3      0      0      1      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      0      1      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0
#  c 1      0      0      1      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      0      1      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0
#  d 0      0      1      1      1      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      0      1      0      1      0      1      1      0      1      0      0      1      1
#   values
#ind Q99877 Q99879 Q9Y2T7
#  a      0      0      1
#  b      0      0      0
#  c      0      0      0
#  d      1      1      1
```

We get the total number of each element with `colSums`.

```
cS <- colSums(tbl)
```

If we need to get the output as in the OP's post, we can `melt` the `list` output to create a 2 column data.frame.  From this, we convert to 'data.table' (`setDT(`), grouped by 'value' column , we get the `length` of `unique` elements of 'variable' and also `paste` together the `unique` elements.

```
library(data.table)
res <- setDT(melt(lst1))[, list(No= uniqueN(L1),
      columns= toString(unique(L1))) ,.(string=value)]
head(res,2)
#    string No columns
#1: P67809  2    a, d
#2: Q9Y2T7  2    a, d
```

Comment: @Mol Sure I will add the description now

Comment: I got a warning using melt Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped . it means some of the strings which are not repeated will be discard ?

Comment: @Mol It is because you have `factor` columns.  Nothing to be worried about.

Comment: @Mol Thank you for the feedback.  Glad it helped you.

Comment: do you know which functions I must use to remove those strings which appears more than 10 times from the original data (mydata) ?

Comment: @Mol Try `v1 <- colSums(tbl) >10; v2 <- trimws(names(v1)[v1]);  v3 <- v2[nzchar(v2)]; lapply(mydata, gsub, pattern = paste(v3, collapse="|"), replacement="")`

Comment: How can I thank you ? it replaces ; instead them. what should I do to replace nothing? Also I used as.data.frame(lapply(mydata, gsub, pattern = paste(v3, collapse="|"), replacement="")) to get the output as a data frame, is it correct ?

Comment: @Mol It is because the delimiter was there.   Perhaps `mydata[] <- lapply(mydata, function(x) gsub(";(?=;)|(?<=;);", "", gsub(paste(v3, collapse="|"), "", x), perl=TRUE))`

Comment: thanks , still some columns ; remains , probably it is always some remaining. I will do that buy xls and manually . Again thanks for all your help

Comment: @Mol  Perhaps `gsub(";(?=;)|(?<=;);|^;|;$", "", gsub(...`

Comment: can I use the above code when my data is not strings but values ? actually I used it and I saw it works but I just want to be sure if it is OK !?

Comment: @Mol `gsub` takes numbers as well.  For example `sub("2", "", c(23, 42))`

Comment: @Mol It's too late here.  Signing off for today.

Comment: do you think today you can have a look at my question ? I have been trying my best but it made me crazy with no success !!! I could not get it done . I will really appreciate if you could help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707323/how-to-rearrange-an-order-of-matches-between-two-data-frames

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be:

```
res <- apply(mydata, 2, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, ";")))
un <- unique(unlist(res))
res2 <- sapply(un, function(x) lapply(res, function(y) as.numeric(x %in% y)))

res2

  P67809 Q9Y2T7 P42356 Q8N8J0 A4QPH2 P35908 P19338 P15924 P14923 Q02413 P63241 Q6IS14
a 1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      0      0      0     
b 0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1     
c 0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1     
d 1      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0     
  P62979 P0CG47 P0CG48   Q16658 P62851 Q07955 Q06830 P62807 O60814 P57053 Q99879 Q99877
a 0      0      0      0 0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0     
b 1      1      1      1 0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0     
c 1      1      1      1 1      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0     
d 1      1      1      0 0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1     
  Q93079 Q5QNW6 P58876 P62750 Q969S3
a 0      0      0      0      0     
b 0      0      0      0      0     
c 0      0      0      0      0     
d 1      1      1      1      1   

as.data.frame(t(apply(t(res2), 1, function(x) cbind(sum(as.numeric(x)), paste(names(x)[which(as.logical(x))], collapse = ",")))))
       V1    V2
P67809  2   a,d
Q9Y2T7  2   a,d
P42356  1     a
Q8N8J0  1     a
A4QPH2  1     a
P35908  1     a
P19338  1     a
P15924  1     a
P14923  1     a
Q02413  2   b,c
P63241  2   b,c
Q6IS14  2   b,c
P62979  3 b,c,d
P0CG47  3 b,c,d
P0CG48  3 b,c,d
        2   b,c
Q16658  1     c
P62851  1     c
Q07955  1     d
Q06830  1     d
P62807  1     d
O60814  1     d
P57053  1     d
Q99879  1     d
Q99877  1     d
Q93079  1     d
Q5QNW6  1     d
P58876  1     d
P62750  1     d
Q969S3  1     d
```

Comment: Thanks , I already liked your answer. I will check your answer too

Comment: I have asked a question which no one answers and i have been busy to solve it desperately with no success, I will appreciate if you could have a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707323/how-to-rearrange-an-order-of-matches-between-two-data-frames

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach with `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` and `gather` from `tidyr`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

splitted <- cSplit(mydata, splitCols = names(mydata), sep = ";") %>% gather() # Split cols and melt data
splitted$key <- substring(splitted$key, 1, 1) # Lose irrelevant string
table(splitted) # Generate frequency table
```

Comment: Thanks , I already liked your answer. I will check your answer too

Comment: I have asked a question which no one answers and i have been busy to solve it desperately with no success, I will appreciate if you could have a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707323/how-to-rearrange-an-order-of-matches-between-two-data-frames